# How to write Hashset values to the console?

Tags: c#, linq, hashset

How do I write the values of a `hashset` to the console? I do not want to use a `foreach` loop.

```
HashSet<string> hashSet=new HashSet<string>();
hashSet.Add("Employee");
hashSet.Add("Employee1");
Console.WriteLine(hashSet.Select(x=>x));
```

**Output**

```
System.Linq.Enumerable
```

**Expected output**

Employee,Employee1

Answer (score 11):

You can use `String.Join`:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", hashSet));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
hashSet.ToList<String>().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

This will iterate over the hashSet and call `Console.WriteLine` on each item

Comment: Why do you need to `stop console`?

Comment: When console run you can stop the execution and view the output can use "Console.ReadLine();" and when you press a button execute restart. But this if of topic. Is not necessary for solve your problem.